# Low Search - Search in Title and/or Grid Field

Tags: search, low-search

New to the lovely Low Search, so apologies for likely dumb question.

I've a single Input search form, that I'd like to use to search both entry titles (in one channel/collection) as well as one specific Grid field.

So far I seem to be able to get Entry Title results with:

```
{exp:low_search:form result_page="root/search_results" }
  <fieldset>
    <label for="keywords">Keywords</label>
    <input type="search" name="keywords" id="keywords" />
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
  </fieldset>
{/exp:low_search:form}
```

Or, results from the custom Grid field with:

```
{exp:low_search:form result_page="root/search_results" }
  <fieldset>
    <label for="keywords">Keywords</label>
    <input type="search" name="search:downloads:reference" id="reference" />
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
  </fieldset>
{/exp:low_search:form}
```

I don't seem to be able to get an either/or type result going on.  On a basic level, I'd only really want the entry_title / url_title.  I'm likely missing a key fundamental of the setup somewhere along the line so all help hugely appreciated even if it involves calling me dense ;)

Ta!

*EE 2.8.1 / Low-Search 3.1.6*

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend creating a Collection where you only add weight to the Title and the Grid field. Make sure the `reference` column in the Grid field's settings is marked as searchable. If it wasn't searchable before, you might need to re-save the entries so it populates the `exp_channel_data` table, which in turn Low Search uses to build its index.

Then you could use this:

```
{exp:low_search:form result_page="root/search_results" }
  <fieldset>
    <label for="keywords">Keywords</label>
    <input type="search" name="keywords" id="keywords" />
    <input type="hidden" name="collection" value="my_new_collection" />
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
  </fieldset>
{/exp:low_search:form}
```

...where `my_new_collection` is the collection described above.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the '[search:title](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/filters#field-search)' parameter instead of keywords, and use that with your grid search:

```
{exp:low_search:form result_page="root/search_results" }

    Title: <input type="search" name="search:title">
    Grid: <input type="search" name="search:downloads:reference">

    <button type="submit">Search</button>
{/exp:low_search:form}
```

Update: Or alternatively, using a keyword search field and adding the field searches to the results tag:

```
{exp:low_search:results 
    query="{segment_3}" 
    search:title="{low_search_keywords}"
    search:downloads:reference="{low_search_keywords}"
    limit="10"
}
  ...
```

Comment: Hi.. that would work.. but obviously adds a second input tag.  I'm trying to get this working on one "shared" input if that is possible :)

Comment: In that case, you should be able to use the keywords as the search field and then add the grid and title search as parameters to the results tag.